# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#

I thought this would work, but apparently it doesn't. Any suggestions please?

```
if (c.ArrivalTime = DateTime.MinValue && c.ExpiryTime = DateTime.MinValue)
{

}
```

then I got this, *Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime'*

Comment: I blame lack of coffee when I have these type of brain fades.

Comment: arhhh, of course "==", I changed that to "=" myself this morning. Sorry, I won't harass you guys next time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `==` for equality operations in C#.

Please see section 1.4 Expressions in the C# language specification.

Answer (score 4):

you are missing equality operator ==

Please use  this way

```
if (c.ArrivalTime == DateTime.MinValue && c.ExpiryTime == DateTime.MinValue)
```